# npm install - preserve existing files in node_modules

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I have taken over a NodeJS project where, for convenience, some symlinks have been placed in the `node_modules` directory, which has been version controlled (just with the symlinks, not with any packages).

Upon running `npm install` to install the packages, the entire directory is replaced and those files are deleted, causing the script that runs after the install to fail as it depends on those files existing.

```
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "deployment/prepublish"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^9.0.8",
    "bulk-require": "^0.2.1",
    "bulkify": "^1.1.1",
    "deasync": "^0.1.4",
    "del": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-angular-gettext": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-compass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-merge": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.3",
    "gulp-rev-all": "^0.8.18",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.4",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "jshint": "*",
    "lodash": "*",
    "merge-stream": "^0.1.7",
    "q": "*",
    "request": "*",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
    "stringify": "^3.1.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-transform": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

How do I ensure that these files are preserved upon `npm install`? I know for a fact this used to work in earlier versions of npm but I haven't seen anything in the changelogs.

- NodeJS Version = v5.4.1
- NPM Version = 3.3.12

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When `npm install` is run, it will examine the `package.json` file and attempt to install any dependencies listed that are not already installed to the `node_modules` directory. If there are no dependencies listed, it replaces the entire `node_modules` directory.

To preserve the files in the `node_modules` directory, you can do the following:

1. Install a module and have it added to the `dependencies` list in the `package.json`.
2. Move the symlink files into the module's folder.

Comment: I didn't really understand your answer - I've added more of the package.json so you can see what's going on. I realise that me just showing `dependencies` as an empty object could have been misleading. This is a front-end build tool and so all the dependencies are only required for dev.

Comment: do you need me to add more information or does your answer still stand?

Comment: You don't need to add any more information. I'm currently investigating the issue.

Comment: We resolved this for now but adding some `git checkout` commands to restore those deleted files as part of the post `npm install` scripts, but this is a hacky solution.

Comment: I know it's been 5 years, but is there any update? Currently in my CI/CD I'm doing an npm install and save the node_modules folder. When the node_modules in empty, then it installs just fine. When the previous content is still there, they get deleted by another npm install. (from 1122 fodler, down to 82). What gives? Why does npm install remove any package at all?